# Consequence of a Power Series Convergence at a Point

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence, divergent-series

My Elementry Differential Equations book by Boyce, (10th edition) claims the following about power series convergence:

"If the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} (x-x_{0})^n$ converges at $x= x_{1}$, then it converges absoultely for $\left | x-x_{0} \right | < \left | x_{1}-x_{0} \right |$"

This statement makes sense if the series converges absolutely at $x = x_{1}$. But is the claim also true if the series converges conditionally at $x = x_{1}$?

Comment: Yes, it is always true. That is an important aspect of the theorem. It means that only by knowing the convergence in one point, you gain an open interval (or even an open ball in the complex case) of convergence, and this is a big deal, no matter about conditional or absolute convergence in $x_1$. E.g., the real series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^n} {n} $ converges conditionally in $-1$ and absolutely in $(-1,1)$

Comment: Very well written, thank you for the answer !!

Answer (score 0):

Let $ R $ be the radius of convergence.

this means that if $ \sum a_n(x_1-x_0)^n $ converges, then

$$|x_1-x_0|\le R$$

So,
$$|x-x_0|<|x_1-x_0| \implies$$
$$|x-x_0|<R \implies $$
$$\sum a_n (x-x_0)^n \; is \; absolutely\; convergent$$

Comment: Ok, so the book meant the series is absolutely convergent at $x=x_{1}$?

Comment: @AAA4568 No, this is true if $ |x_1-x_0|<R$

Comment: let's say we don't know the radius of convergence at all, can we claim that if the power series converges conditionally at $x = x_{1}$  then it converges absolutely at $\left | x-x_{0} \right | < \left | x_{1}-x_{0} \right |$ ??

Comment: @AAA4568 Yes {[{}}{}}}}{}{}